# Сложение данных из 2-х массивов

Tags: массивы, php

Доброго времени суток.

Вопрос такой. 
Есть 2 массива:

```
$a = [
'one' => 1,
'two' => 3
'three' => 6,
'five' => 7
];

$b = [
'one' => 3,
'two' => 9,
'three' => 4
'six' => 0
];
```

Нужно объединить значения в этих 2-х массивах, чтобы получилось:

```
$sum = [
'one' => 4,
'two' => 12,
'three' => 10,
'five' => 7,
'six' => 0
];
```

Подскажите, плиз, не понимаю, как это делать...(
Пробовал через foreach, но запутался в ключах и все перепутал...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Посмотреть пример](http://ideone.com/fWJpqE)**

```
$sum = [];

$shared_keys = array_keys(array_intersect_key($a, $b));

foreach ($shared_keys as $shared_key) {
    $sum[$shared_key] = $a[$shared_key] + $b[$shared_key];
}

$sum = array_merge($sum, array_diff_key($a, $b), array_diff_key($b, $a));
```

---

```
Array
(
    [one] => 4
    [two] => 12
    [three] => 10
    [five] => 7
    [six] => 0
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Для коллекции, [еще один вариант](http://ideone.com/lr6Upf):

```
$res = call_user_func_array('array_merge', array_map(function($k, $v1, $v2){
    return [$k => $v1 + $v2];
}, array_keys($a+$b), $a, $b));
print_r($res);
```

Answer (score 1):

array_merge ? ( http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-merge.php )

Comment: не подходит, ибо он объединяет массивы, а не значения.
что то типа
[code]
$sum = [
'0' => [
'one' => 1,
'two' => 3
'three' => 6,
'five' => 7
],
'1' => [
'one' => 4,
'two' => 12,
'three' => 10,
'five' => 7,
'six' => 0
]
];
[/code]
пробовал merge...