# Ошибка: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int

Tags: php, массивы

Доброго времени суток!

Я уже писал недавно свою проблему с объединениями элементов массива
([Сложение данных из 2-х массивов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/357061/php-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%B7-2-%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=357083#357083))

Теперь проблема возникла там, где я ее никак не ожидал. Использую фреймворк laravel.
У меня есть 2 таблицы, из которых я получаю данные, и объединяю элементы в них, собственно в чем и был первый вопрос. Но проблема возникла вот какая. При том подходе, что мне посоветовали, у меня возникает ошибка:

> **Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int**

Данные из базы получаются следующего вида:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[201]
      public 'id_users' => int 8
      public 'password' => string '$2y$10$2itBbB57ntl3I7WNMhmwhuUTMfBodQpTbnpDsOGpCQTzakbihKKzO' (length=60)
      public 'email' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'phone' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'username' => string 'MrRino' (length=6)
      public 'bl' => int 26800
      public 'exp' => int 0
      public 'lvl' => int 1
      public 'remember_token' => string 'yD3hsRzSH3xudziysZO0gTeu9vv4LsowV2Z22dbXTxCn3NeWjeQrv9vteXwS' (length=60)
      public 'updated_at' => string '0000-00-00 00:00:00' (length=19)
      public 'created_at' => string '0000-00-00 00:00:00' (length=19)
      public 'id' => int 1
      public 'users_id_users' => int 8
      public 'param28' => int 0
      public 'param29' => int 0
      public 'param30' => float 0
      public 'param31' => float 0
```

и второй запрос, соответственно, однотипный, только с другими данными.
Вот мне их нужно объединить. Объединить объяснили как, теперь не понятно как бороться с этой ошибкой.
Погуглил, ничего путного не нашел( Может, кто сталкивался с данной проблемой и знает, как с ней бороться? Прошу помощи!

Comment: @Александр Маслов, а вы переводили текст ошибки?
И покажите, пожалуйста, где именно возникает ошибка, место в коде, которое указывает интерпретатор.

Comment: @ua6xh, а что тут переводить: Объект класса stdClass не может быть преобразован в int.
Использую пример, который дал @Deonis, интерпретатор всегда ругается на суммирование: return [$k => $v1 + $v2];
Все переменные у меня int и float. Пробовал выставлять все int, это не помогло, след. дело не в этом. 
Та конструкция, что выше в примере, это через var_dump.

Answer (score 1):

stdClass возвращает объект, а не массив, и все манипуляции с объектом приведут к той ошибке, что возникла у меня.
Проблема решается следующим образом:

```
function objectToarray($data)
   {
       $array = (array)$data;
       foreach($array as $key => &$field){
           if(is_object($field))$field = $this->objectToarray($field);
       }
       return $array;
   }
```

и будет вам счастье!